# Cannot get data from json_encoded array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5, redis

i have key and value datas. key is an array. i want to foreach this key data. I use laravel 5. my json_decoded array like :

```
Collection {#1288 ▼
  #items: array:4 [
    "{"id":1,"title":"abc","path":"abc-path"}" => 19
  ]
}
```

But i can not fetch key data like i wanted my code :

```
@foreach($trendings as $key => $value)

 {{ $key->id }}

@endforeach
```

it gives ' Trying to get property of non-object  ' error. but if write code like :

```
 @foreach($trendings as $key => $value)

     {{ $key }}

   @endforeach
```

it gives me

```
{"id":1,"title":"abc","path":"abc-path"}
```

but i want them use in my html. how can i fetch them ?

Comment: Your `$key` is json string. You need to `json_decode($key)`  to get access to fields. But more reasonable way - is to fix your collection. Why json string is the key and not a value?

Comment: This is json decoded data. This is redis data and redis does not allow me to use value

Comment: You probably don't __understand__, but I can repeat: `{"id":1,"title":"abc","path":"abc-path"}` is a __json__ string. To get access to properties, you __must__ `json_decode` it.

Comment: u mean i must json_decode $key ?

Comment: Yes, I mean it.

Comment: so how can i decode in foreach ? `@foreach($trendings as json_encode($key) => $value)` doesn't work

Comment: Decode in controller and pass data in required format to view.

Comment: i am decoding $trendings in controller

Comment: So then decode the keys of `$trendings`.

Comment: Try `$trendings =[
    '{"id":1,"title":"abc","path":"abc-path"}' => 19
  ];

foreach($trendings as $key => $value) {
    echo json_decode($key)->id;
}` using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: it works now !!!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, view should not execute a json_decode.
I expect view to get already decoded variables, i think that if your data is not completly decoded something is missing before the view.

Of course i would rather work on fixing what's wrong before than patching your view.

Comment: No , i make json_decode in controller for $trendings, but in here in it needs second json_decoding for $key. Cuz it’s still a json data after $trendings’s decode process.

Comment: I understand, seems like something is missing before, how comes after the first parsing that $key is not decoded?Maybe something strange when it get encoded or when in gets decoded before. I would rather fix what's wrong before than patch your code with a second decoding